# laravel 5.2 if else to query database

Tags: laravel, if-statement

stuck on a form that allows the user to enter a value into a choice of two fields. I can query the database using one field but want to add more range to database queries. With the following code below when i try to access the page to query it just shows me a white screen.

```
public function index()
 {
   $data = $request->all();

   if(!empty($data['pstoreNum']))
   {
   $pstoreNum = $data['pstoreNum'];


    $result = DB::table('perfumes')->where('StoreNumber','=',$pstoreNum)
              ->get();

    return view('perfumes',compact('result'));
  } 
  else if(!empty($data['pweekNum']))
  {
      $pweekNum = $data['pweekNum'];


      $result = DB::table('perfumes')->where('WeekNumber','=',$pweekNum)
             ->get();

       return view('perfumes',compact('result'));
   }

  }
```

My routes file simple calls the index function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add query functions within your query like so

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $result = \DB::table('perfumes')->where(function($query) use ($data) {
        if(!empty($data['pstoreNum'])) {
            $query->where('StoreNumber', '=', $data['pstoreNum']);
        }
        if(!empty($data['pweekNum'])) {
            $query->where('WeekNumber', '=', $data['pweekNum']);
        }
    })->get();

    return view('perfumes',compact('result'));

  }
```

You can then use the one query and add multiple wheres on various conditions.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses

Comment: Error message Undefined variable: request

Comment: That must be an error from the mark up you supplied. Try adding Request $request to the function. As long as you are posting to the function index

Comment: Thanks for the reply. used the Request $request and then error message of DB not found so added use DB and works.!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as an answer when you are done :) Good luck with the rest of your project